# Como mandar uma imagem por post no angular

Tags: angular, post, image

Gostaria de saber como eu posso estar enviando uma imagem para uma api no angular 6 através do método post.

Primeiro eu devo codificar essa imagem em base 64 e ai eu mando todo aquela codificação como valor de uma chave????

Answer (score 1):

No Angular 6, você pode mandar os bits da imagem no corpo da requisição POST.

```
sendImage(imagem) {
  return this.httpClient.post(URL, imagem, {headers: this.headers});
}
```

E então o servidor processaria os bits da imagem e guardaria o arquivo na memória. Você pode usar a mesma lógica com a requisição PUT.

Fazer o envio através de uma requisição GET culmina em colocar os bits da imagem no header da requisição.

Comment: o que você quer dizer com enviar os bits da imagem? é através da codificação da base 64?

Comment: Sim. Se você usar um input de tipo `file`, você pode associar uma função ao evento change `(change)="funcao()"`, e toda vez que o valor do input for alterado, ele realiza essa função.